# OpenGL for OSX not perfect circumferences

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl

I am developing a app that use picking selection using color depth in OpenGL for Mac. The selection works great, but I observed that OpenGL not draw perfect circles (circunferences). I use GL_LINE_LOOP for render 360 segments for complete a close circunference. But if, I see the render in SELECTION mode I observe some kind of bites (triangles in white) over the circunference, 4 in total for each circle.

Is a OpenGL problem or I am doing something wrong?

This is the code for draw each circunference.

```
glLineWidth(10.0f); // Exaggerated for image.
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {

        calcX = radio * cos((i * M_PI) / 180) + offset_x;
        calcY = radio * sin((i * M_PI) / 180) + offset_y;
        glVertex3f(calcX, calcY, offset_z);
    }
glEnd();
```

[image: Tree circunferences with bits]

Comment: It almost looks like the end of the line is angled in that way...

Comment: Graphics hardware can (and does) vary in how it renders lines, particularly wide ones.  Depending on your hardware, it may draw wide lines by rendering multiple one-pixel wide lines by shifting the line's coordinates.  Your best approach for what you show is probably to render a triangle strip in the shape of the ellipse having its width match your desired line width.  It's also likely that will render faster than wide lines (modern hardware much prefers to render triangles).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "radical7, for the the suggest to use Triangles instead lines. I was able to obtain a perfect RING, works as smooth .

This is the code:

```
        color = 0.00277778;
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {

            glColor4f(color, 0, 0, 1.0f);
            calcX = radio * cos((i * M_PI) / 180) + offset_x;
            calcY = radio * sin((i * M_PI) / 180) + offset_y;
            glVertex3f(calcX, calcY, offset_z);
            radio +=20;

            calcX = radio * cos((i * M_PI) / 180) + offset_x;
            calcY = radio * sin((i * M_PI) / 180) + offset_y;
            glVertex3f(calcX, calcY, offset_z);
            radio -=20;

            color += 0.00277778;
        }
        glEnd();
```

Result:

[image: Perfect ring...]